# Any other method than copying bits to an ANativeWindow buffer?

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, nativewindow

I'm using native window in android to show a video in a surface view.
Here's the part of my code.

```
ANativeWindow_lock(window, &windowBuffer, NULL);
memcpy(windowBuffer.bits, buffer,  size);
ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(window);
```

But the memcpy is taking too much time. Is there any other method without memcpy so that I can directly use the buffer allocated in native code? I want to fill the surface view completely with data in buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surfaces aren't buffers, they're queues of buffers.  Anything headed to the display will be double- or triple-buffered.

You can generate your output directly into the buffer returned by `ANativeWindow_lock()`.  Because it's (at least) double-buffered, there is no penalty for locking the next buffer right after you unlock the previous one -- you won't prevent the compositor from seeing the just-finished frame by immediately calling lock.

See the Android graphics architecture doc for more details, particularly [this section](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#triple-buffering).